# Group by and sum deep nested lists with streams

Tags: java

I have three classes:

```
public class Supply {
    private final List<Compartment> compartments;

    public List<Compartment> getCompartments() {
        return compartments;
    }

    public Supply(List<Compartment> compartments) {
        this.compartments = compartments;
    }
}

public class Compartment {
    private final String itemId;
    private final List<Unit> units;

    public String getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public List<Unit> getUnits() {
        return units;
    }

    public Compartment(String itemId, List<Unit> units) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
        this.units = units;
    }
}

public class Unit {
    private final String containerNumber;

    public String getContainerNumber() {
        return containerNumber;
    }

    public Unit(String containerNumber) {
        this.containerNumber = containerNumber;
    }
}
```

Given these classes, I want to come up with a list, map, tuple, or type of: `itemId` and `containerNumber`
combinations and their quantities.

That is, if I have:

```
Unit unit1 = new Unit("unit");
Unit unit2 = new Unit("unit");
Unit unit3 = new Unit("another_unit");

Compartment compartment = new Compartment("foo", newArrayList(unit1, unit2, unit3));

Supply supply = new Supply(newArrayList(compartment));
```

Using Java streams, I would like to get something like:

```
"foo", "unit", 2
"foo", "another_unit", 1
```

I've tried a number of combinations with `groupingBy`, `toMap`, etc., with no such luck.

My latest attempt is something like:

```
Map<String, List<Map<String, List<Unit>>>> result = supply.getCompartments()
    .stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Compartment::getItemId,
            mapping(compartment -> compartment.getUnits().stream().collect(groupingBy(Unit::getContainerNumber)), toList())));
```

Which I feel is pretty close, but I guess I couldn't use a `Map` since the key, `itemId` could be there multiple times with a different `containerNumber`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea. What you're missing is that you need a flat mapping collector, instead of a mapping collector, as the downstream collector.

Sadly, this collector isn't built-in in Java 8, but it will be present in Java 9 ([JDK-8071600](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8071600)), with [`Collectors.flatMapping(mapper, downstream)`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-). For Java 8, one can reimplement it like this:

```
static <T,U,A,R> Collector<T,?,R> flatMapping(Function<? super T, ? extends Stream<? extends U>> mapper, Collector<? super U, A, R> downstream) {
    BiConsumer<A, ? super U> downstreamAccumulator = downstream.accumulator();
    return Collector.of(
            downstream.supplier(),
            (acc, t) -> {
                try (Stream<? extends U> stream = mapper.apply(t)) {
                    if (stream != null) {
                        stream.sequential().forEach(u -> downstreamAccumulator.accept(acc, u));
                    }
                }
            },
            downstream.combiner(),
            downstream.finisher(),
            downstream.characteristics().toArray(new Characteristics[downstream.characteristics().size()])
           );
}
```

Then you can use this collector to build your wanted map:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Unit>>> map =
    supply.getCompartments()
          .stream()
          .collect(groupingBy(
            Compartment::getItemId,
            flatMapping(c -> c.getUnits().stream(), groupingBy(Unit::getContainerNumber))
          ));
```